# Focusing to an object JQuery

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

i'm using Sweet Alert Plugin to displaying an alert, if i clicked OK, i want to focus in my textbox.

my problem is :
1. if i'm used `timer` property from sweet alert, the focus function in jquery is not working
2. but if i'm not used property from sweet alert, the focus function in jquery is working fine.

maybe somebody can help me to solve my problem :D

my script :

```
swal({
  title: "Auto close alert!",
  text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",
  timer: 2000
});
$('.classMyTextField').focus();
```

ps : i tried to use 2 focus function between swal function, but still not working :D

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code?

```
swal({
  title: "Auto close alert!",
  text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",
  timer: 2000
}, function(){
  swal.close();
  $('.classMyTextField').focus();
});
```

Comment: i tried, but still can't focusing... are you have another solution ??

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a callback function as the second parameter of swal()

```
swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",
    text:  "I will close in 2 seconds.",
    timer: 2000
  },
  function(){
    // SweetAlert confirmed, do something

    $('.classMyTextField').focus();
  }
);
```

To do something when SweetAlert is **confirmed** or **cancelled**:

```
swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",
    text:  "I will close in 2 seconds.",
    timer: 2000
  },
  function(isConfirmed){
    if(isConfirmed){
       swal("Confirmed!", "You confirmed the alert.", "success");
       $('.classMyTextField').focus();
    }
    else{
       swal("Cancelled!", "You cancelled the alert.", "warning");
    }           
  }
);
```

**UPDATE:**

To show only notification without the Confirm or Cancel buttons:

```
swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",
    text:  "I will close in 2 seconds.",
    timer: 2000,
    showConfirmButton: false,
    showCancelButton: false
  },
  function(){
    // alert closed
    $('.classMyTextField').focus();
  }
);
```

Comment: but i just want to displaying a notification without any action, is it possible focusing without any action?? are you have another solution ??

Comment: @MuhammadBima Sweet Alert is asynchronous. You have to use a callback function to do something when it's closed.

Comment: This should work with or without using timer. Maybe you're not selecting your textbox properly. Will you show us your HTML?

Comment: I just updated this answer with an example for showing only alert with auto-close using timer.

Comment: @doncadavona - same result, but this time the alert isn't closed, if alert want closed, i must use swal.close() function again... and the result ? the text box isn't focused :(

Answer (score 0):

The best and effective way to do this is to use `.then(function(){` just before closing the swal with ";".

Using your code, it will be like that:

```
swal({
  title: "Auto close alert!",
  text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",
  timer: 2000
}).then(function(){
  $('.classMyTextField').focus();
});
```